# Shifting extent and data values of NetCDF with GDAL

Tags: gdal, extents, netcdf

I am processing OSCAR third-degree ocean currents data from:

https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/OSCAR_L4_OC_third-deg

These are netCDF files. Longitude extends from 20 E to 420 E to avoid a break in major ocean basins. Data repeats in the overlap region. I would like to shift the extent and the data to a target extent of -180 -90 180 90. When I shift the extent, the data doesn't follow. I am running:

```
gdalwarp -of netCDF -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te -180 -90 180 90 u.nc u2.nc -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0
```

This gives me the following result, as viewed in the netCDF viewer Panoply:

[image]

As you can see, the data is only appearing in the overlap with the original extent instead of throughout.

How might I write a gdal command to shift the data along with the extent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to re-project OSCAR data with this command:

```
gdalwarp \
    -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=200" \
    -t_srs EPSG:4326 \
    -te -180 -90 180 90 \
    -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 \
    NETCDF:oscar_vel10126.nc:u \
    u.tif
```

Because of the longitude extent, PROJ lon_wrap param can be anything between 200 and 240.